# Can we use EXPORT command to copy hadoop data to aws S3?

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I'm researching for copying Hadoop data to S3. And explored different option.I came to know that we can use EXPORT command to copy the files to another cluster. Can we use Export command same way to copy data and metadata to AWS S3?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP1**: Create an S3 Bucket

**STEP2**: Use distcp utility to copy data from your hadoop platform to the S3 bucket created in STEP1.

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://hdfs_host:hdfs_port/hdfs_path/hdfs_file.txt s3n://s3_aws_access_key_id:s3_aws_access_key_secret@my_bucketname/
```